# Listview not adding second item, store only one item and rewrites it on refresh

Tags: android, listview

Hello I have Activity with tabs and in second tab I have Listiew that pull data from sql and show result but problem is when I check with logcat all data fetched correctly but listview only shows the last one, and when I add new item to database it also show the last one but not previous as list and when I am tryin to resfresh also not working PLEASE HELP SOS yesterday it work what wrong even If I recreate activity it doesnt works
Tab2 Activity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.example.sultan.diplom.bazaMoiTemy.Contact;
import com.example.sultan.diplom.bazaMoiTemy.DataBaseHandler;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Tab2 extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    List<Contact> contacts;
    DataBaseHandler db;
    ListView mListView;
    List<String> your_array_list,listcena,job,opisan;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_2,container,false);
        mListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
        db = new DataBaseHandler(getActivity());
        contacts = db.getAllContacts();
        your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        listcena = new ArrayList<String>();
        job = new ArrayList<String>();
        opisan = new ArrayList<String>();
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);



        for (Contact cn : contacts) {
            String log = "ID:" + cn.get_id() + " Name: " + cn.get_name()
                    + cn.get_cena()+" "+cn.getJob()+" "+cn.get_opis();
            your_array_list.add(cn.get_name());
            listcena.add(cn.get_cena());
            job.add(cn.getJob());
            opisan.add(cn.get_opis());
            Log.e("AAAAAAAAAAA,",cn.get_name()+"");

        }

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                your_array_list );
        mListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {
                String name = your_array_list.get(position);
                String jobs = job.get(position);
                String opis= opisan.get(position);
                String cen = listcena.get(position);


                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Temys.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                intent.putExtra("jobs", jobs);
                intent.putExtra("opis", opis);
                intent.putExtra("cen", cen);

                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

            }
        });
        return v;
    }

       @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                db=null;
                contacts = null;
                db = new DataBaseHandler(getActivity());
                contacts = db.getAllContacts();

                your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
                listcena = new ArrayList<String>();
                job = new ArrayList<String>();
                opisan = new ArrayList<String>();

                for (Contact cn : contacts) {
                    String log = "ID22222:" + cn.get_id() + " Name: " + cn.get_name()
                            + cn.get_cena()+" "+cn.getJob()+" "+cn.get_opis();
                    your_array_list.add(cn.get_name());
                    listcena.add(cn.get_cena());
                    job.add(cn.getJob());
                    opisan.add(cn.get_opis());
                    Log.e("1111111111111,",log);

                }
                arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getActivity(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        your_array_list );
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                mListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);













            }
        }, 4000);
    }
}
```

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" android:id="@+id/swipe">
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Contacts:

```
public class Contact {

    // private variables
    int _id;
    String _name;

    String _cena;
    String _opis;
    String job;
    public int get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(int _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public String get_cena() {
        return _cena;
    }

    public void set_cena(String _cena) {
        this._cena = _cena;
    }

    public String get_name() {
        return _name;
    }

    public void set_name(String _name) {
        this._name = _name;
    }

    public String getJob() {
        return job;
    }

    public void setJob(String job) {
        this.job = job;
    }

    public String get_opis() {
        return _opis;
    }

    public void set_opis(String _opis) {
        this._opis = _opis;
    }


    public Contact(String _name, String job, String _opis, String _cena) {
        this._name = _name;
        this.job = job;
        this._opis = _opis;
        this._cena = _cena;
    }



    // Empty constructor
    public Contact() {

    }

    // constructor


    // constructor


    // constructor



}
```

Answer (score 1):

change you onRefresh() block with

```
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            db=null;
            contacts = null;
            db = new DataBaseHandler(getActivity());
            contacts = db.getAllContacts();

            your_array_list.clear();
            listcena.clear();
            job.clear();
            opisan.clear();

            for (Contact cn : contacts) {
                String log = "ID22222:" + cn.get_id() + " Name: " + cn.get_name()
                        + cn.get_cena()+" "+cn.getJob()+" "+cn.get_opis();
                your_array_list.add(cn.get_name());
                listcena.add(cn.get_cena());
                job.add(cn.getJob());
                opisan.add(cn.get_opis());
                Log.e("1111111111111,",log);

            }
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, 4000);
}
```

your creating new object of ArrayList and ArrayAdapter every time of refresh, no need to it only you have to clear the previous data, add new data and inform the same to ArrayAdapter that data set is changed by calling arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();.

Comment: 03-04 15:27:25.072 9010-9010/com.example.sultan.diplom E/1111111111111,: ID22222:2 Name: 123123 123 Сантехник
03-04 15:27:25.072 9010-9010/com.example.sultan.diplom E/1111111111111,: ID22222:5 Name: asdfsdf123213123 sdfsdf Программист
03-04 15:27:25.072 9010-9010/com.example.sultan.diplom E/1111111111111,: ID22222:4 Name: asdsfsdfsdf sdfsdf Сантехник
03-04 15:27:25.072 9010-9010/com.example.sultan.diplom E/1111111111111,: ID22222:1 Name: qweqwerwerwerwer wqrwe Программист
03-04 15:27:25.072 9010-9010/com.example.sultan.diplom E/1111111111111,: ID22222:3 Name: zxczxc zxc Сантехник

Comment: even if I am recreate activity

Comment: please comment all code inside onRefresh() and tell me all Records are displaying or not.

Comment: coment then I should restart activity?

Comment: you mean in listview or log?

Comment: rebuild project and rows in Listview

Comment: Thank you  problem was that I put Listview in Scrollview when I delete it its works fine Thank you very much for arranging refresh method

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all my problem was that I put Listview in Scrollview when I delete it its works fine